# fseek and ftell function can not work in loop in my file concatenation program

Tags: c, file, concatenation

I am writting a program concatinate many files into one. My destination is let user insert file quantity "n" with name "xxx", then I will read from file "xxx001.txt" to "xxx00n.txt". Whenever the file opened, I use fseek function to move to end of file and use ftell to get the file size. When I open source files one by one to count the file size by 'while' or 'for' loop, it just work one time and stop. Please check out my code and let me know why i get the error below then help me to optimize my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>   
void main()
{

    int n;
    int i = 1;
    char filedest[100];
    char filesource[100];
    char format[5] = ".txt";
    long  sourcesize, destsize = 0;

    printf("Insert file quantity: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    rewind(stdin);
    printf("Insert name of list key word: ");
    gets_s(filesource);
    rewind(stdin);
    while(i<=n)
    {
        rewind(stdin);
        sprintf(filesource, "%s00%d%s", filesource, i, format);
        FILE *fsource = fopen(filesource, "rb");
        fseek(fsource, 0L, SEEK_END);
        destsize += ftell(fsource);
        fclose(fsource);
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. eliminates the problems listed in the comments to the question.
2. correctly formats the file name for each iteration through the loop
3. properly checks for errors for everything but the *_s functions
4. does not check for overflow of the variable: `destsize`

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main( void )
{

    int n;

    char filesource[100];
    char filename[1024];
    long destsize = 0;

    printf("Insert file quantity: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);

    printf("Insert name of list key word: ");
    gets_s(filesource);

    for( int i=1; i<=n; i++ )
    {
        sprintf( filename, "%s00%d.txt", filesource, i );
        printf( "file name:%s\n", filename);

        FILE *fsource = fopen(filename, "rb");
        if( !fsource )
        {
            perror( "fopen failed" );
            continue;
        }

        if( fseek(fsource, 0L, SEEK_END) != 0)
        {
            perror( "fseek failed" );
            fclose( fsource );
            continue;
        }

        long position = ftell( fsource );
        if( position == -1 )
        {
            perror( "ftell failed" );
            fclose( fsource );
            continue;
        }

        destsize += position;

        fclose(fsource);
    }
}
```